# How to send $this->uname & $this->email to controller (controller/ctrl_crud.php)

Tags: php, model-view-controller

How to send `$this->uname` & `$this->email` to controller data to controller/ctrl_crud.php

**create.php**

```
<?php
    include 'FullScreenLayout.php';
    class index {
        public $uname, $email;
        public function get_data() {
            if ( isset($_POST) ) {
                $this->uname = $_POST['form_uname'];
                $this->email = $_POST['form_email'];
            }
        }
        public function createForm(){
            $createHTML = <<<EOT
            <form method="POST">
                <div class="main_form">
                    <div class="md-form">
                        <input type="text" id="form_uname" name="form_uname" class="form-control" placeholder="User Name">
                    </div>
                    <div class="md-form">
                        <input type="text" id="form_email" name="form_email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address">
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-submit">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </form>
    EOT;
        return $createHTML;
        }
    }
    $ObjFullScreenLayout = new FullScreenLayout();
    $ObjIndex = new index();
    $ObjIndex->get_data();
    echo $ObjFullScreenLayout->header();
    echo $ObjIndex->createForm();
    echo $ObjFullScreenLayout->footer();
    ?>
```

**controller/ctrl_crud.php**

```
<?php
class ctrl_crud {

}
?>
```

Comment: Your question is confusing please clarify what you are trying achieve and what did you try so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send those data to the **constructor**

```
include 'controller/ctrl_crud.php';
public function get_data() {
    if ( isset($_POST) ) {
        $this->uname = $_POST['form_uname'];
        $this->email = $_POST['form_email'];
        new ctrl_crud($this->uname, $this->email);
    }
}
```

**controller/ctrl_crud.php**

```
class ctrl_crud {
    function __construct($uname, $email){
        // use uname and email here
    }
}
```

Comment: can I add this ctrl_crud class in ctrl_crud.php file?

Comment: ya. I got. Thank you so much

Comment: yeah, I have updated the question. If that fixes the issue. Please accept as an answer.

Comment: This answer is better than mine, assuming you **need** to post to the same page and you **can** change the constructor of `controller/ctrl_crud.php`

Comment: Thanks, I think he wants to do some process with $_POST data on create.php and also want to send that data to ctrl_crud.php

Answer (score 0):

Just add an action to your form that points to the page you want to send the data like so:

```
<form action="controller/ctrl_crud.php" method="post">
```